# How to solve the exception W/ConnectionTracker(12409): Exception thrown while unbinding

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
page_turn: ^1.0.1
dio: ^3.0.10
sqflite: ^1.3.2+1
path_provider: ^1.6.24
firebase_core: ^0.5.3
firebase_messaging: ^6.0.2
firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.4
firebase_performance: ^0.3.1+5
```

android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Also i have added "multiDexEnabled true" inside defaultConfig{}

As you can see I am implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging, and I am trying to call another user-defined function inside the "onMessage" callback, but I am getting such exception:

```
W/ConnectionTracker(12409): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(12409): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ls@3008fa2
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1870)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1848)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:755)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714081@20.47.14 (120400-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714081@20.47.14 (120400-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at lt.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714081@20.47.14 (120400-0):9)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at ld.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714081@20.47.14 (120400-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714081@20.47.14 (120400-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(12409):     at iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714081@20.47.14 (120400-0):5)
```

Comment: Any update on this exception ????